# Containerized vault won't run in ECS

Tags: docker, amazon-ec2, containers, amazon-ecs

I have a setup for vault container together with a consul server and a bash container.

I have followed this setup:
https://medium.com/@pcarion/a-consul-a-vault-and-a-docker-walk-into-a-bar-d5a5bf897a87

I have tested it locally and it works and I can store secrets within the vault. The problem lies when I tried to deploy it into the AWS ECS. I have created the images for them and use the available image for consul and vault. The containers run smoothly but sadly the vault cannot connect with the consul resulting with an error log of:
2018-10-08T07:39:03.983Z [WARN ] migration_check: Get http://:9500/v1/kv/vault/core/migration: dial tcp :9500: connect: connection refused

​

I have tried editing the security group to accept all traffic for the mean time but it still won't connect to the consul

Answer (score 0):

Hi I think is an easy problem you need to put your consul cluster behind an ELB or use the ECS service discovery feature, the problem is because you are not passing the consul address to your vault container

in your vault container you need to declare an environment variable like this

VAULT_LOCAL_CONFIG={"backend":{"consul":{"address":":9500","advertise_addr":"http://${LOCAL_IP}", "path":"vault/"}},"listener":{"tcp":{"address":"0.0.0.0:8200","tls_disable":1}}}
  command: server

This is assuming you have consul cluster in one set of containers and vault in other

Comment: I have declared an environment variable like that but I will try as mine doesn't include the "command: server". 

Regarding the ELB and Service Discovery, is it required to have them even though I have specified the IP for the vault to connect to and adding the link option in the task definition?

Comment: If you only have one consul no, but will be better to use a cluster of services remember amazon could ask for reboot or shutdown your instances any time